# How to display negative values below the x-axis in C3.js

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

This is how I want it to look like negative values below x-axis and negative values wrapped in circular brackets.

[image]

**C3.js Code**

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto : "#totalDollarFlow",
    size : {
        height : 400,
        width : 700
    },
    title : {
        text : data.title
    },
    data : {
        x : labels,
        columns : data.columns,
        axes : {
            data1 : 'y',
        },
        type : 'bar',
        types : {
            data1 : 'line',
        },
        names : {
        },
        colors : {
            data1 : '#2ca02c',

        },
        selection : {
            enabled : true,
            draggable : false,
            multiple : true,
            grouped : true
        }
    },
    subchart : {
        show : false
    },
    point : {
        show : false
    },

    zoom : {
        enabled : true,
        rescale : true
    },
    grid : {
        y : {
            show : true
        }
    },
    regions : [ {
        axis : 'y',
        start : 186,
        end : 187,
        class : 'regionY'
    } ],
    axis : {
        x : {
            type : 'category',
            tick : {
                rotate : 90,
                centered : true,
                fit : true,
                multiline : false,
                culling : {
                    max : 60
                }
            },
        },
        y : {
            label : {
                text : '$s Millions',
                position : 'outer-middle'
            },
            tick : {
                format : d3.format("$,")
            }
        },
    }
});
```

How the chart looks like at present.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if everything you want is possible but at least you can get close to it. For your y-Axis you can use this format:

```
y : {
            label : {
                text : '$s Millions',
                position : 'outer-middle'
            },
            tick : {
               format: function (d) { 
                    const realNumber = d*1000000;    
                    return realNumber.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
                }
            }
        }
```

To get a line at 0 you can define a grid-line for the y-axis at position 0. You can also set a text here, but only one text to describe what this line is for and not like your ticks. I think this is even better than having the timestamp floating in your chart.

```
grid : {
        y : {
            show : true,
            lines: [
                {value: 0},
            ]
        }
    }
```

This line might be a little bit thin, but you can make it thicker when you change its css. I think it was `c3-ygrid-line`. To get more information you can always use [the reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html)